# jest mocking module functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to make assertions on jest mocked functions and my code is like this

```js
const saveProductMock = jest.fn((product) => {
  //someLogic
  return
});

jest.mock('./db', () => {
  return {
    saveProduct: saveProductMock
  }
})
```

my assertion should be like

```js
expect(saveProductMock.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(product)
```

but I got the following error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'saveProductMock' before initializing **at the line saveProduct: saveProductMock**

Comment: Do you have any `import` statements in your test?

Comment: yes, but not for the db module

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete example? Please include the `import` statements

Comment: I can't share the code actually...but I will try to provide the setup with the imports

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock()` is [hoisted](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). As a result, the code is actually ran like:

```
jest.mock('./db', () => {
  return {
    saveProduct: saveProductMock
  }
})

const saveProductMock = jest.fn((product) => {
  //someLogic
  return
});

//WAS HERE
```

Solution would be to put the login inside `jest.mock();`.

```js
jest.mock('./db', () => {
    return {
        saveProduct: jest.fn((product) => {
            //someLogic
            return
        })
    }
})
```

Other solution is to simply mock the entire module then, define explicit return value to use.

```
const db = require('./db');
jest.mock('./db');

it("example", () => {
    db.saveProduct.mockReturnValue(123);
    /** different types of return methods */
    // db.saveProduct.mockResolvedValue(123);

    const product = db.saveProduct();
    const expectedProduct = "xyz";
    expect(product).toBe(expectedProduct)
})
```